# how to open site from IP address

Tags: web, dns, ip

I uploaded a cakephp based application on new server. But, dns is not defined for that IP. When I try open website by IP address directly it shows Error 404. Can anyone please suggest me that how can I open website on browser?

Thanks

Comment: Even I can open cpanel from IP address

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the webserver isn't configured to accept connections using the direct IP. If you're using a apache webserver, you should most likely change the virtual host. More information here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Nginx has a similar system which is explained here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Most web servers have some similar system. This makes it possible to host multiple websites with several DNS on one physical computer. If you can't access the configuration files yourself, you should contact your host.

Comment: But I can open cpanel from IP Address